# History of the Vertex Disjoint Cycle Cover with Minimal Edgeweight Sum

Tags: graph-theory

Questions:

- who first posed the problem of determining a collection of (directed) cycles, whose edgeweight sum is minimal and, for which each vertex belongs to exactly one of the cycles?
- who came up with the solution of duplicating the vertex set and thus reducing the problem to a minimum-weight bipartite matching?

Answer (score 1):

I just found an online publication related to the problem: ["The Cycle Cover Problem" by J.L. Szwarcfiter and B.L. Wilson, Technical Report No 131 1979, University of Newcastle upon Tyne, UK](https://assets.cs.ncl.ac.uk/TRs/131.pdf).

As that report's investigation of the cycle cover problem is inspired by Karp's list of 21 NP-complete problems, I would be surprised if an earlier reference could be found.

Edit:
in that report is also a (the first?) definition of 3-dimensional matching.

Comment: There is a wiki dedicated to the first author: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayme_Luiz_Szwarcfiter

Comment: also a nice summary of Szwarcfiter's contributions to mathematics https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs13173-011-0054-2.pdf